# echo "" - баг или нет?

Tags: php

Если написать про echo "", т.е. вывод пустого места, без пробелов и вообще каких-либо символов, то считается ли это багом/експлоитом/ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ""; // нормально
echo; // ругается на точку с запятой
```

Вывод: если пишете эхо, хоть что-то надо вывести. Хоть пустую строку.
Еще можно так:

```
echo null; //
```

но нафига? ©

Comment: knes, так мне нужно просто, вот и спрашиваю, надо вывести пустое место, которое не занимает место. Вот такой вот парадокс. :)
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: обязательно расскажите зачем. Требую!!! =)))

Comment: Может быть ТС ищет [flush()](php.net/flush) ?

Comment: вряд ли: echo никогда не заменит flush.

Comment: Заменит, если включен ob_implicit_flush в [конфиге](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.implicit-flush) или [явно](http://php.net/ob_implicit_flush) или заполнен буфер. Но суть не в этом, просто у человека незнакомого с буферизацией вывода в PHP может возникнуть иллюзия, что вызвов echo отправляет что-либо на сервер.

Comment: echo "&nbsp;" не вариант?

Comment: Народ требует объяснений для чего это нужно! :)

Comment: Выдать пустой ответ?

Comment: Просто плагин wp выводит свои копирайты, не хочу весь код перебирать вот и решил echo очистить и все.

Comment: а echo удалить не вариант?

Comment: Ну там перед этим идет if и потом echo, т.е. будет "если", но не будет "то" - я считаю это неправильным. Даже не пробовал полностью убирать echo, т.к. думаю, что возникнет ошибка.